# Como criar um diálogo de abrir arquivos com a biblioteca SDL?

Tags: c, linux, sdl

Estou fazendo um reprodutor de áudio muito simples em C (no Ubuntu) para um trabalho da faculdade, e estou usando a biblioteca SDL para criar janelas (interface gráfica) junto com a SDL_mixer para reproduzir o áudio.

O problema é: preciso de uma forma de o usuário apontar o arquivo de música que ele quer reproduzir, tipo uma *dialog box* que retornaria o diretório do arquivo escolhido pelo usuário para que eu pudesse passá-lo ao SDL_mixer e executá-lo.

Na internet só achei alguns tutoriais em C# para Windows.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Aqui você não achará um tutorial. Em qual parte do seu código exatamente você está enfrentando problema? Talvez voce poderia inclusive compartilhar esse trecho de código que voce fez e esta encontrando um problema, se for o caso.

Comment: O SDL não tem funções para criar janelas de abrir ficheiro. Portanto vai ter que criar uma nova, ou usar uma biblioteca complementar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode instalar o `GTK+` (também é em C) e utilizá-lo para mostrar um `File Chooser Dialog`, onde o usuário selecionará o arquivo de música. Daí para frente você pode fazer com o `SDL` mesmo.

Algumas referências:

- [GTK Getting Started](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/gtk-getting-started.html)
- [File Chooser Dialog](http://www.geany.org/manual/gtk/gtk/GtkFileChooser.html)

Para instalar o GTK:

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```